# Xbox One Detect network connection type

Tags: uwp, xbox, xbox-one

I am developing a UWP application for XBOX One and for analytics purposed I want to detect if the device is connected through Ethernet or WiFi.

I tried the Windows API for that but I found out it is not yet supported for Xbox One.

Anyone has any workaround for this issue?

Comment: [Windows Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/networkhelper) has Connection Type. Can you try that and see if it helps? I never tested that on XBox. Just a hunch.

Comment: @AVK If you check Commuity Toolkit NetWorkHelper source code, u will find that it also use [NetworkAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkadapter) class to detect the ConnectionType, but this class doesn't support on XBOX.

Comment: yes, I am trying to find a workaround without using this API

Comment: @MohamedAdly For now, there's no API for you to do it on XBOX. You could submit a **Feature Request** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the docs regarding what exactly is supported on uwp for Xbox, many are out of date. Most of the networking classes will work, and you can use IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.IanaInterfaceType to tell WiFi from Ethernet.